# Remap 2-d pandas dataframe to 3-d xarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I currently have a large 2-d pandas dataframe of time-series values (1-year or more) which I would like to remap to a 3-d xarray. The pandas dataframe has a column_id which corresponds to a (lat, lon) coordinate in another reference dataframe.

Is there any inherent functionality which can achieve this in xarray?

Comment: you probably need to add more information to your question to help others know what exactly you are trying to do. Also, you usually want to show that you've tried something and articulate why it hasn't worked. Maybe you can show us an example of your dataset and what your desired output is.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the best practice is to implement a multi-index in pandas using .set_index(), then subsequently to convert this into an xarray dataset using .to_xarray().

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('falcon', 'bird', 'predator', 389.0, 2),
                   ('parrot', 'bird', 'prey', 24.0, 2),
                   ('lion', 'mammal', 'predator', 80.5, 4),
                   ('monkey', 'mammal', 'prey', np.nan, 4)],
                  columns=['name', 'class', 'diet', 'max_speed', 'num_legs'])

df.set_index(['name', 'class' , 'diet'], inplace=True)
myArray = df.to_xarray()
print(myArray)
```

Result:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (class: 2, diet: 2, name: 4)
Coordinates:
  * name       (name) object 'falcon' 'lion' 'monkey' 'parrot'
  * class      (class) object 'bird' 'mammal'
  * diet       (diet) object 'predator' 'prey'
Data variables:
    max_speed  (name, class, diet) float64 389.0 nan nan nan ... 24.0 nan nan
    num_legs   (name, class, diet) float64 2.0 nan nan nan ... nan 2.0 nan nan
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html